# Faster logout script PHP

Tags: php, session

I have login functionality in PHP and that is working perfectly fine. When i click on `Logout` then it takes around 10 seconds to logout from session.

How can i make it faster?

My website is hosted on shared server.

My `logout.php` looks like as below

```
<?php
  session_start();
  unset($_SESSION['logdname']);
  header('location: ./');
?>
```

`$_SESSION['logdname']` has been set while logging into the website.

Comment: replace `header('location: ./')` with `header('location: /')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To destroy a session, add `session_destroy();` and `exit;` after header in order to stop further execution if there's more code below that.

```
<?php
session_start(); // start the session
$_SESSION['logdname'] = "John";
session_destroy(); // destroy active session

$_SESSION = array();
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
exit;
```

Test code to show you the proof:

```
<?php
session_start(); // start the session
$_SESSION['logdname'] = "John";
echo $_SESSION['logdname']; // will echo John
session_destroy(); // destroy active session

$_SESSION = array();
echo $_SESSION['logdname']; // will not echo John
```

Otherwise, placing `session_start();` below will generate warnings such as

> Warning: session_destroy(): Trying to destroy uninitialized session

and

> Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent

Comment: is it required to mention domain as `http://example.com` .. can not `header('location:./')` work ?

Comment: @Gags It is recommended in the manual to use a full http call. If your way works, you can use that if you wish.